# Unable to clear prior sorted data

Tags: excel, vba

I used multiple sorting and wanted to clear sorting and applying new sorting in the same sheet but its not working,  would be helpful if anyone can help me with this by guiding how to use sort clearing code in the below:

```
Sheets("LEMC").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Primary Owner"

LSTRW = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Primary Owner")
.Range("A:O").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
.Range("A:O").Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
.Range("P1") = "Test"
.Range("P2:P" & LSTRW).Formula = "=IF(D2=D1,1,0)"
.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
.Range("A:P").Sort Key1:=Range("P1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Thanks experts

Regards
Suresh

Comment: Once you sorted you replaced the content of the rows, so if you remove sorting nothing happens. You should resort it based on a RowID.

Comment: You mean what we sorted before should be resorted with opposite sign (If used ascending then we should do now with Descending and if smallest to highest used then now we should do highest to smallest)?

Comment: Well that compleltly depends on what the original data looked like. Assuming that your sorting procedure just randomly distributed the data the only way to get back to the original data is to add a seperate column for RowID before sorting. Then just simply give the cells in that columns the value that equals the row number they are in. Then if you want to go back to the original situation you simply sort on RowID in ascending order.

Comment: Thank a lot for Explanation :) will try to add another column with row number sequence which will be helpful if i don't want sorting then i can go back to the first stage... Thanks Luuklag Good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make use of a column that contains an ID for each row. This can be the same as the row number. You can easily sort on this after you sorted on a different parameter to return your dataset to the original order.